# How to read all lines from stdin in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, stdin

I know it is possible to use a while loop to fetch a multi-line input from stdin using the readLine function.

Is there a function in kotlin to retrieve all lines at once from stdin without using a JVM api?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53575064/clean-way-of-reading-all-input-lines-in-kotlin/53575400#53575400

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
val input = generateSequence(::readLine).joinToString("\n")
print(input)
```

The first line gets the multi-line input from stdin and put it into a variable.

The `generateSequence` is a function from kotlin standard library, `kotlin.sequences` package, that takes another function and calls it until it returns null. In the end it will return an instance of Sequence, that is a sequence of elements that can be iterated over.

The `::readLine` part is a way to pass the `readLine` function, that it is used to read from stdin, to the `generateSequence` function. Just calling `readLine()` without `::` will cause a compiler error since `generateSequence` expects for a lambda, not a string.

The joinToString method belongs to the Sequence class. It will iterate over its elements and join them using the given separator, which, in this case, is a new line (\n).

Finnaly at the second line we just print the result to the stdout.